# What does "parked in the red zone" mean?

Tags: plot-explanation, reservoir-dogs

Nice Guy Eddie took Mr. Pink and Mr. White to ditch cars that were parked near their warehouse,
leaving Gangster Blonde and a hostage cop tied to a chair in the warehouse. He then walked up
to the cop:

> Blonde: Alone at last. Guess what. **I think I'm parked in the red zone**.
> (Blonde laughs)

I know that ‘parked in the red zone’ usually means that a vehicle is parked in a
no-parking zone, But it doesn’t seem to make sense in this context because there is
no apparent connection between parking and the situation at hand.

What does "parked in the red zone" mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"*a hostage cop tied to a chair*" and "*parked in the red zone*" are two faces of the same coin. In both cases you'll be in trouble with the police.

The fun resides in the seriousness of each situation and the way he compares them. Usually, you don't expect getting fined or a small ticket when you kidnap/beat/shoot a cop, like you expect when you park in a no-parking zone.

Blonde jokes about the situation while "*minimizing the risk*" of retaliation. Doing so, he belittles the importance of the police officer.